# How to request API Gateway endpoint using PHP AWS SDK?

Tags: php, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk

I have `https://api-id.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com/stage` endpoint, how to query it using SDK?

Found `ApiGatewayClient` but can't figure out how to use it properly and didn't find any helpful usage examples on the internet.

Some methods require some ConnectionID or another arguments, I am sure there should be a simple way.

**EDIT**
For instance my Api url is `https://myawesomeid.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/` where "myawesomeid" is my ApiId.
Querying it like this:

```php
$this->client->getStage([
            'restApiId' => 'myawesomeid',
            'stageName' => 'execute-api',
        ]);
```

And got such error:

```
Error executing \"GetStage\" on \"https://apigateway.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/restapis/myawesomeid/stages/execute-api\"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `GET https://apigateway.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/restapis/myawesomeid/stages/execute-api` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:\n{\"Message\":\"User: arn:aws:iam::804737862755:user/staging-api-s3-assets is not authorized to perform: apigateway:GET on r (truncated...)\n AccessDeniedException (client): User: arn:aws:iam::804737862755:user/staging-api-s3-assets is not authorized to perform: apigateway:GET on resource: arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1::/restapis/myawesomeid/stages/execute-api because no identity-based policy allows the apigateway:GET action - {\"Message\":\"User: arn:aws:iam::804737862755:user/staging-api-s3-assets is not authorized to perform: apigateway:GET on resource: arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1::/restapis/myawesomeid/stages/execute-api because no identity-based policy allows the apigateway:GET action\"}\n
```

I think I might not have enough permissions, but using Postman I can query my Api endpoint by this credentials I use to connect via code.
What I need is just to make GET/POST to my API. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you build client with [needed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.ApiGateway.ApiGatewayClient.html) parameters, then you call proper methods. E.g. [getStage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-apigateway-2015-07-09.html#getstage):

```php
$client = new ApiGatewayClient({
   'credentials' => [
        // This is optional, as AWS SDK will take it directly from _SERVER superglobal
        'key' => $_SERVER['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
        'secret' => $_SERVER['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
   ],
   ...
});

$response = $client->getStage([
    'restApiId' => 'api-id',
    'stageName' => 'execute-api',
]);

$body = json_decode($response->get('Body'), true);

echo $body['cacheClusterStatus'];
```

Comment: Hey @Justinas and thanks for your reply! Tried like you proposed, and edited my post a bit because there are not a lot of characters allowed for commenting. Could you please check my original post for more details?

Comment: @Clark So your message clearly states that use `arn:aws:iam::804737862755:user/staging-api-s3-assets` does not have enough permissions. So fix that on your own.